# SWTBotTree expand node by regular expression

Tags: java, regex, swtbot

I'd like to use SWTBotTree.expandNode (final String nodeText, final boolean recursive) function with a String that is not always exactly the same. The beginning of the string is the same but the end can be varying. I thought it can be solved with reg. exp. something like: "constant part of the string"+".*" but it was not recognized as a reg. exp. What should I do??

Comment: Please show your code. And the proper exception. What do you mean "not recognized as a regexp"?

Comment: how do you apply the regex to the Tree?

Comment: My code looks like: 'SWTBotTree projs = bot.tree();
'String ProjectName="ProjectName";
String temp=ProjectName+".*";
SWTBotTreeItem proj = projs.expandNode(temp,false);'

I got the following exception:
org.eclipse.swtbot.swt.finder.widgets.TimeoutException: Timeout after: 5000 ms.: Could not find node with text ProjectName.*

Comment: So the question is that how can I tell the SWTBot to expand a Node with a name starting with "ProjectName" and ends with some various characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure exactly how you are trying to do this, but if you are doing:

```
swtBotTree.expandNode("constant part of string" + ".*", true);
```

Then you are most likely doing it wrong...

The [javadoc for expandNode](http://eclipse.uib.no/technology/swtbot/archives/2.0.0.204-dev/ganymede/dev-build/apidocs/org/eclipse/swtbot/swt/finder/widgets/SWTBotTree.html) gives no mention that it supports regular expressions...

Looking into [the source](https://dev.eclipse.org/sonar/resource/index/378) (just some version I found when searching), `expandNode` uses another method called `getItem(...)`. That method does something like `if (item.getText().equals(nodeText))`. In other words, that method uses string equality comparison, not regex matching.

In Java, there is support for regular expressions (take a look at [Pattern javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and [Matcher javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) or on [String.matches(...) javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29)), but only if that functionality is used in  the implementation. You cannot pass a regex to a method which expects a normal String and expect it to do regex matching.

**Short answer:**

Java has classes which provide regex functionality, but the `SWTBotTree.expandNode(String, boolean)` method does not support regex.

**EDIT:**

As far as I understand, there is no direct support in `SWTBotTree` for doing regex/wildcard lookups.

If you desperately want to do this, you could try something like:

```
 for(SWTBotTreeItem item : swtBotTree.getAllItems()){
     if(item.getText().matches("some regex goes here")){
         item.expand();
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I thought that the problem is something like that, but I hoped there is a solution for this.

Comment: @vdani Added a suggestion about how it is probably possible to achieve this.

Answer (score 3):

(Somewhat speculative, but hopefully helpful.)

If "constant part of the string" contains characters which have special meaning in a regular expression, that could easily be a problem. The way to solve this is to use [`Pattern.quote`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29). For example:

```
// ^ to anchor the match to the start of the line/string. May not be required.
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^" + Pattern.quote(expectedPrefix) + ".*");
```

Of course I'd only use this if I *had* to use regular expressions. Otherwise I'd just use:

```
if (actualText.startsWith(expectedText))
```

Comment: +1 Jon Skeet fact in action: Jon Skeet answers a question without actually knowing the problem - and solves it. (in two different ways...)